# CMake failed to compile in Linux

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

I am altering a CMake file which works on Windows to create a shared object in Linux.

The CMake file generates a makefile and when I did "make" on Linux, it built objects of foo libraries and it displays linking of all four libraries. For example:

> Linking CXX static library lib_foo_d.a

and the final shared object

> Linking CXX static library lib_scen_files_d.a

but at the end it displays

> /usr/bin/ld: lib_foo3/lib_foo3_d.a(chap_alt_scence_defs.cpp.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object;
>   recompile with -fPIC
>   lib_foo3/lib_foo3_d.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have tried a few other options, but no joy.  Below is my CMakeLists.txt.  Any help/criticism will be beneficial to me.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )
CMAKE_POLICY( SET CMP0017 NEW ) 

PROJECT( disk_space_model )
INCLUDE( ../libs/helper_functions.cmake )
INCLUDE_THIRD_PARTY_SFC()
find_path_for_libs()

add_s_library( lib_foo1 )
add_s_library( lib_foo2) 
add_s_library( lib_foo3) 
add_s_library( lib_foo4) 

SET(    HEADER_FILES 
        stdafx.h
        INS_sensor_model.h
)

SET(    SOURCE_FILES
        Disk_space_model.cpp
)

SET(    RESOURCE_FILES 
        "Disk Space DLL.rc"
        resource.h
)

COMMON_SETUP()
set( LIB_FILES 
        lib_foo
        lib_foo1
        lib_foo3 
        lib_foo4 )

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--export-all-symbols")
ADD_LIBRARY( disk_space_model SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${RESOURCE_FILES}  ${CMAKE_HELPER_FILES} )
SET_OUTPUT_DIRS( disk_space_model )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( disk_space_model ${LIB_FILES} )
```

Thanks ...

Comment: You use far too many custom macros that we don't know (cause they are in external files)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is telling you what is wrong: the object is used in a shared library, but wasn't compiled with `-fPIC`. You need to add this flag somehow.

When using CMake 2.8.9 or later, you can simply set property `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` on the target(s) in question (the static libraries).

With prior versions of CMake, you need to add the flag directly to the targets' `COMPILE_FLAGS` properties (in the proper spelling for your compiler, probably just `-fPIC`).

Comment: thanks for comment . Well I am using cmake-gui of ver 2.8.7  so I reckon first option is  not for me.  About 2nd option , you meant that in my case it complains about foo3 so I should add "COMPILE_FLAGS properties" in CmakeLists of foo3 directory?

Comment: @samprat Yes; objects which go into a Linux shared library must be compiled as Position Independent Code (PIC).

Comment: .. It works. Thanks a lot for the help. It was bit painful steps as I need to make changes in lot of libraries and i was bit sceptical but at the end it worked very well. Thanks a ton for rescuing me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build shared library on Linux all sources, who's object files linked to it, must be compiled as relocatable (-fPIC option as linker complains). You try to link static libraries lib_foo1 lib_foo2 lib_foo3 etc into your shared library, and it fails.
So possible solutions:

- Build shared version (.so) of each library lib_foo1 lib_foo2 .. in addition to static one (.a)
- Build static libraries with -fPIC parameter
- Do not link static libraries to shared library, but link them to the app. This may not be possible if functions from static libraries are used in your shared lib.